# Java extension methods for LiveData

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata

In Kotlin there's an extension method observeOnce (https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-livedata-observe-once-only-kotlin/) which is the behaviour I'm looking to replicate in Java. It's to my understanding from googling that you can't use Kotlin extension methods in java (may be wrong), so I've got two options of using SingleEventLiveData which I've implemented and am not keen on, and removing my observer once used;

```
final LiveData<List<String>> stringsLiveData = mViewModel.getStrings();

stringsliveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), strings -> {
    // Do stuff with data here
    stringsLiveData.removeObservers(getViewLifecycleOwner());
});
```

Is there an equivilant method that can be used as the link above so;

```
mViewModel.getStrings().observeOnce(getViewLifecycleOwner(), strings -> {
    //Do stuff here
});
```

**Edit**: As per the accepted answer below (modified to compile) I've got;

```
class LiveDataUtils {
    public static <T> void observeOnce(LiveData<T> liveData, Observer<T> observer) {
        liveData.observeForever(o -> {
            liveData.removeObserver(observer);
            observer.onChanged(o);
        });
    }
}
```

and a simple usage of this;

```
LiveDataUtils.observeOnce(
    mViewModel.getStrings(),
    strings -> {
        // Do some work here
    }
);
```

Comment: You can use extension methods from Java. They're just static methods with the first Parameter being the receiver. I'm not sure if they restricted this somehow in the case of live data, but might be worth a shot

Comment: Yeah I've been playing around with it, but can't seem to get anything to work the way I want sadly.

Comment: You shouldn't remove ALL observers, you should only remove the `observer` you gave the method.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Updated to only remove the individual observer, what's your thoughts on observe(owner, o) vs observeForever(o)

Comment: That it depends on what you are doing. Although the *intended* way of doing things is to only receive events after `onStart`, and before `onStop`. I've used observeForever inside ViewModel, but I should have used Transformations.switchMap (which internally uses observeForever/removeObserver).

Comment: Hmm, i've updated it to be observeForever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Kotlin extension function is resolved statically, which means that you can do the same in Java by using static functions. It is not as readable or as intuitive as the extension functions, but it does the same job.

Create a util class with a static method:

```
public class LiveDataUtils {

public static <T> void observeOnce(LiveData<T> liveData, Observer<T> observer) {
    liveData.observeForever(new Observer<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(T t) {
            liveData.removeObserver(this);
            observer.onChanged(t);
        }
    });
   }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, so it might have some errors. The point was to show you how you can replace extension functions in Java.

EDIT: Updated according to follow up by @Marek Potkan, since this is the accepted answer. As I mentioned, I haven't tested the code and I provided a wrong reference by mistake.

Comment: I would recommend moving the removeObserver above the `observer.onChange` since you could get another item through the LiveData before you remove it.

Comment: I've modified this code a bit to make it compile and it works just fine, thanks! I'll edit my answer to show the correct code.

Comment: @Ge3ng has a valid point, you can make the switch to avoid receiving multiple items. Glad I could help, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

@deluxe1 answer wouldn't work. It is removing `observer` called `observer`, but that's not the one which is used in the `observeForever` method. Expanded version should be used instead of the lambda function here:

```
public static <T> void observeOnce(LiveData<T> liveData, Observer<T> observer) {
    liveData.observeForever(new Observer<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(T t) {
            liveData.removeObserver(this);
            observer.onChanged(t);
        }
    });
}
```

I have tested both approaches.